# Application crashed when trying to load Json using retrofit to a recyclerView in a fragment in a tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-tablayout

so to be more specific i have an activity which contains a tablayout each tab should basically load a standalone fragment containing a recycler view an i want the data retrieved from the api using retrofit to be loaded in the recyclerView bases on user action
so this is the activity :

```
public class RestaurantLogoView extends AppCompatActivity implements LiteFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, RegularFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "RestaurantLogoView";
        public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //TODO
    public static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;

    private String chosenArea;
    TextView locationTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext());
        //remove this if you still didnt get data in the fragment
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());

        locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_tv);
        chosenArea = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Object");
        locationTv.setText(chosenArea);
        locationTv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        //TODO i added this lately not sure what its supposed to do but consider removing it
    }

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */

//
//
//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_restaurant_main_view, menu);
//        return true;
//    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == locationTv) {
            Intent o = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AreaList.class);
            startActivity(o);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "What do you want to eat today?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        String tabTitles[] = {getString(R.string.regular), getString(R.string.lite)};
        Context context;


        SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    new RegularFragment();
                    return RegularFragment.newInstance(TAG, position);
                case 1:
                    new LiteFragment();
                    return LiteFragment.newInstance(TAG, position);

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

    }

}
`
```

This is the first fragment which should be shown in my first tab

```
public class RegularFragment extends Fragment {

    OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    public static final String REGULAR_PARAM1 = "lite";
    View RootView;
    List<RestaurantModel> regularRestaurants;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private Call<RestaurantElKbeer> callbackCall;
    private String TAG = "RegularFragment";
    //new
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public RegularFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment newInstance(String param, int position) {

        //TODO it might be important i didnt know why i created it
        Fragment fragment = new RegularFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(param, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        regularRestaurants = requestRegularList();
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //new
        RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_regular, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        initializeAdapter();
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        return RootView;
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), regularRestaurants);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }


    private List<RestaurantModel> requestRegularList() {
        List<RestaurantModel> myRestaurantsList = new ArrayList<>();
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter();
        API api = restAdapter.getApi();
        // URL: https://betaweb.jeebley.com/services_new/services.php?action=search&langId=1&countryId=21&cuisineType=1&cuisineId=all&areaId=1&delvType=1

        Call<RestaurantElKbeer> call = api.getRestaurants("search", "1", "21", "all", "1", "1");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantElKbeer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RestaurantElKbeer> call, @NonNull Response<RestaurantElKbeer> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
                    RestaurantElKbeer restaurantResponse = response.body();
                   List<RestaurantModel> list = restaurantResponse.getRestaurantModel();
                if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        String name;
                        name = list.get(i).getRName();
                        names.add(name);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + names.get(i));
                    }

                }
                else
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse(regular): RestaurantModelList is null");
                    }
                    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    recyclerView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), ChooseYourLanguage.class);
                        i.putExtra("Object", getId());
                        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<RestaurantElKbeer> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: failed RegularFragmentCall");
            }
        });
        return myRestaurantsList;
    }


    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the Fragment host's standard options menu.  You
     * should place your menu items in to <var>menu</var>.  For this method
     * to be called, you must have first called {@link #setHasOptionsMenu}.  See
     * {@link RestaurantLogoView#onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu}
     * for more information.
     *
     * @param menu     The options menu in which you place your items.
     * @param inflater
     * @see #setHasOptionsMenu
     * @see #onPrepareOptionsMenu
     * @see #onOptionsItemSelected
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu) {
        super.setHasOptionsMenu(hasMenu);
    }
}
```

And this is my RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<RestaurantModel> items;
    private Context ctx;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RestaurantModel> items) {
        this.ctx = context;
        this.items=items;
    }


    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private SharedPref sharedPref;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, RestaurantModel obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView imageView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_card_view);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName_section_label);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_label2);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantImageView);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.restaurant_card_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        RestaurantModel p = (RestaurantModel) payloads.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(p.getRName());
        if (!p.getDelvType().equals("1")) {
            holder.description.setText(p.getJDeliveryTime() + " " + p.getRMinOrderAmt() + " " + p.getJDeliveryCharge());
        } else {
            holder.description.setText(p.getRDeliveryTime() + " " + p.getRMinOrderAmt() + " " + p.getRDeliveryCharge());
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
       holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.i("RecyclerViewAdapter", "onClick: replace with intent to send Restaurant data");
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,int position) {

        final RestaurantModel p = items.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(p.getRName());
        if (!p.getDelvType().equals("1")) {
            holder.description.setText(p.getJDeliveryTime() + " " + p.getRMinOrderAmt() + " " + p.getJDeliveryCharge());
        } else {
            holder.description.setText(p.getRDeliveryTime() + " " + p.getRMinOrderAmt() + " " + p.getRDeliveryCharge());

        }
        holder.cv.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, p, position);

        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore(int current_page);
    }
}
```

This is the exception i'm getting

**

> 06-06 00:11:05.215 10571-10571/com.jeebley.jeebley E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.jeebley.jeebley, PID: 10571
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                            at com.jeebley.jeebley.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:109)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3493)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3310)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
>                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1762)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1606)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1515)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1762)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1606)
>                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1515)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:774)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17687)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2511)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2226)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
>                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6763)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:923)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
>                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:909)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
>   06-06 00:11:05.238 10571-10571/com.jeebley.jeebley I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10571 SIG: 9

**

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing:

```
List<RestaurantModel> list = restaurantResponse.getRestaurantModel();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String name;
    name = list.get(i).getRName();
    names.add(name);
    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + names.get(i));
}
```

As far as I can see in the error trace, your problem is that list is null when you ask for the size, so you should ask if the list is not null before:

```
...
List<RestaurantModel> list = restaurantResponse.getRestaurantModel();
if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String name;
        name = list.get(i).getRName();
        names.add(name);
        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + names.get(i));
    }
}
...
```

EDIT:

In your adapter, modify this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items!=null ? items.size() : 0;
}
```

The method getItemCount() is being called before the array initialization inside the adapter life cycle. That's why you need to check if your list is null or not to avoid npe.

Comment: basically i was just testing something here but what i really want to do is to load the restaurant name , description and min order amount which i will get from the api, so in both cases data isn't displayed and i'm not sure why or in which process the crash happens and debugging is just so irritating i don't know most of the steps going on

Comment: i did the if condition to check the null state and i updated the new exception being thrown can you please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

first, check if restaurantResponse.getRestaurantModel() return null.

```
List<RestaurantModel> list = restaurantResponse.getRestaurantModel();
if(list == null){
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: yes man i did so and updated the exception being thrown above

Comment: i also updated the code above can you please have a look into my recycler view adapter too maybe i'm doing something wrong but i can't get it

Comment: @KareemEl-Bayaa What's on line 109?